# How to use program to check if a two-dimensional constraint set is simply-connected?

Tags: python, matlab, math, optimization

I'm trying to write a program that takes the constraints of a 2-dimensional space as input and outputs whether the space is simply-connected.

I do understand the mathematical concept that the space's fundamental group needs to be trivial, but I'm finding it hard to implement with code.

Is there a more handy way to check whether there are holes in a 2-dimensional space?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.